# Where am I supposed to post a question relating to website management?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have the following question:

> **Best practice to add a page indicating that a website is in maintenance**
>
> I use Spring MVC + Apache tomcat + Apache httpd and I am seeking for
>   best practices in order to redirect all http requests to a page
>   indicating to my users that the website is in maintenance.
>
> Any clue or advice welcome.

Can anyone please let me know on which of the stack exchange sites I am supposed to post it?

Answer (score 5):

[Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) **might** be OK. However:

1. Check their [FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) first to make sure that it's on topic.
2. Reword the question to avoid the subjectivity of "best practice". While there are probably some thing that are better practices than others, I would imagine that a lot of answers are going to start with "It depends".
3. List your specific requirements.
4. Explain what you've already tried (if anything) or what your current thinking is.
5. Avoid asking for "any clue or advice" as that could lead to extended discussion. Something Stack Exchange is bad at.

Comment: @balteo I would also do away with the wording "any clue or advice...", just because that suggests open-endedness. I would further go into detail about what you have tried or what you have investigated, and what trouble(s) you have run into with those possibilities. I *think* Webmasters might be the right place for this (I'm not active there, so do read their FAQ), but I can also say if you think the answer would involve a lot of *code* (in Spring MVC, for example), it *might* be appropriate for Stack Overflow, too. I'm not familiar enough with the tech to know for sure, though.

Comment: I've posted on Webmasters already and will amend my post according to your advice. Thanks.